# Searching answers by votes

Tags: support

Recently I looked through the top hundred or so top-voted questions out of curiosity, but after that I realized I was perhaps more interested in the top-rated **answers**. Is there any way to see the highest-rated answers of all time (site-wide, rather than for a single question)?

If this isn't the case, I'll add the feature-request tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search query `is:answer score:100` returns all answers scored 100 or higher. (Interestingly, there are exactly 99 of them now. What will be the 100th 100-vote answer?)

Results: [answers scored 100 or higher](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a100), sorted by votes.

You can change 100 to any other number, of course. You can add `[tag name]` to filter by tag, `wiki:no` to exclude community-wiki answers, and so on... experiment with "Advanced Search Tips" in the sidebar of search results.

Also, one can do without the `score:` parameter: just search for `is:answer [tag name]` and sort the results by votes.

Comment: [this answer by Arturo](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn/29035#29035) :-)

Comment: @robjohn I see what you did there. As an aside: Arturo is one of [Top 50 users in 2013](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/year/math/2013-01-01?sort=reputationchange&pagesize=50)...

Comment: This is amazing since [his last post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/175626) was on July 26, **2012**. His last comments were later that day.

Comment: Quite amazing that being completely inactive, he still have accumulated such a critical mass of answers that he managed to get over 17,000 points during the passing year.

Comment: I actually just searched for how to do this on the meta after seeing that answer by Arturo (And adding my +1 to it!)

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/edit/153856) data.stackexplorer query shows the top 100 questions, and
[this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/153710/191392/top-answers-by-tag) gives you the results filtered by tag name.

The results of the first query are a little depressing though.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to have this filter by tag, as well? I'm afraid I'm not versed in using stackexplorer.

Comment: (Wish I could upvote again based on your edit... and that's why I'm inclined to filter the results.)

Comment: There's one filtered by tag name.

Comment: @mrf I think both the general query and the by tag-name query will be useful to other users.  Can you edit your answer to include both links?

Comment: @Goos There you are.

Comment: @mrf great, thanks!